# How do I close a custom contextmenu in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, contextmenu

I made a custom contextmenu directive in AngularJs. Now it should be closing when I click anywhere except the custom menu. I binded a click function to the document which closes the menu, but for other elements on the page which has click events on them, have stopped working, and only the document click function is working. How do I solve this problem? 
My Angular code:

```
app.directive('preventRightClick', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        visible: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $ele) {
        $ele.on('contextmenu', '*', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.visible = true;
                // console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY)
                $('.parented').css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY})
            })
        });

        $(document).on('click', '*', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).parents('.parented').length  > 0) {
                // console.log('yes, its parent');
                // console.log($(e.target))
                console.log('Within parent clicked')
            }
            else{
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.visible = false;
                })
                console.log('Outside parent clicked')
            }
        })              
}
};
})
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-if="isVisible" class="parented" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical notclick" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group"> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try angular-click-outside plugin
https://github.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-click-outside
It is easy to use, just use it like that:
`<div class="menu" click-outside="closeThis()"></div>`

Comment: I can't use plugins. I am trying to use this in a pretty big enterprise app. I have just written plain code to get the logic.